# EF Core relationship mapping between itself

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relationship

### Background

Let say there are two tables in the database

`Member`

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tony |
| 2 | Steve |
| 3 | Bruce |
| 4 | Scott |

`MemberRecruit`

| MemberId | RecruitmentMemberId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

Where the `RecruitmentMemberId` is just `MemberId`

And there are two classes

```
public class Member
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<MemberRecruit> Recruits { get; set; }
}

public class MemberRecruit
{
   public int MemberId { get; set; }
   public int RecruitmentMemberId { get; set; }
}
```

With EF Core 3.1, it is easy to create an `OwnsMany` relationship for `member.Recuits` in DbContext, like

```
builder.Entity<Member>(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("Member", "dbo");

    m.HasKey(x => x.MemberId);

    m.OwnsMany(x => x.Recruits, nav =>
    {
        nav.ToTable("MemberRecruit", "dbo");
        nav.HasKey(x => new
        {
            x.MemberId, 
            x.RecruitmentMemberId
        });
        nav.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberId);
    });
});
```

### Question

If I would like to change the class structure to something like

```
public class Member
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<MemberRecruit> Recruits { get; set; }
}

public class MemberRecruit
{
   public int MemberId { get; set; }
   public int RecruitmentMemberId { get; set; }
   public Member Recruitment { get; set; } // This is the recruited member
}
```

Without changing the tables, is there a good practice to map that in DbContext with FluentAPI using `Owns` or `.HasOne.WithMany + .HasMany.WithOne` relationship, so that when I have a `DbSet<Member> Members`, I can query like the following?

```
var recruitments = (await _db.Members.AsNoTrack()
                             .Include(x => x.Recruits)
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == request.Id, token))
                          .Recruits
                          .Select(x => x.Recruitment, token);
return recruitments.Select(x => (x.Id, x.Name));
// if request.Id is 1, return will be [(2,"Steve"),(3,"Bruce")]
// if request.Id is 2, return will be [(4,"Scott")]
// if request.Id is 3, return will be []
```

---

Or with the same two tables, map the following class

```
public class Member
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<Member> Recruitments { get; set; }
}
```

So that the query can be simplified to

```
var member = await _db.Members.AsNoTrack()
                               .Include(x => x.Recruitments)
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == request.Id, token);
return member.Recruitments.Select(x => (x.Id, x.Name));
```

### What I've tried

#### Test 1

```
builder.Entity<Member>(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("Member", "dbo");

    m.HasKey(x => x.MemberId);

    m.OwnsMany(x => x.Recruits, nav =>
    {
        nav.ToTable("MemberRecruit", "dbo");
        nav.HasKey(x => new
        {
            x.MemberId, 
            x.RecruitmentMemberId
        });
        nav.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberId);

        nav.HasOne(x => x.Member) // Added HasOne.WithMany
           .WithMany(x => x.Recruits)
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.RecruitmentMemberId);
    });
});
```

This return

```
var member = await _db.Members.AsNoTrack()
                      .Include(x => x.Recruits)
                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 1, token);
// member.Recurits.Count is 1 instead of 2
// member.Recurits[0].Recruitment.Id is 1 which is incorrect
```

#### Test 2

```
builder.Entity<Member>(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("Member", "dbo");

    m.HasKey(x => x.MemberId);

    m.OwnsMany(x => x.Recruits, nav =>
    {
        nav.ToTable("MemberRecruit", "dbo");
        nav.HasKey(x => new
        {
            x.MemberId, 
            x.RecruitmentMemberId
        });
        nav.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberId);

        nav.HasOne(x => x.Member)
           .WithMany(x => x.Recruits)
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberId); // Change the foreign key
    });
});
```

This return

```
var member = await _db.Members.AsNoTrack()
                      .Include(x => x.Recruits)
                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 1, token);
// member.Recurits.Count is 2 which is correct
// member.Recurits.Select(x => x.Recruitment.Id) are all 1 which is incorrect
```

Comment: Are you sure than one member can have many recruits? I think  one recruiter can have many members. Please explain

Comment: @Serge it's like a company referring system, so one member can recruit others to join as a member and that member can than also recruit someone else. It's just a make up example for the actual use case with similar behavior

Answer (score 1):

Add relations to your classes

```
    public partial class Member
    {
        public Member()
        {
            MemberMembers = new HashSet<MemberRecruit>();
            MemberRecruits = new HashSet<MemberRecruit>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

       

        [InverseProperty(nameof(MemberRecruit.Member))]
        public virtual ICollection<MemberRecruit> MemberRecruits { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty(nameof(MemberRecruit.Recruit))]
        public virtual ICollection<MemberRecruit> MemberMembers { get; set; }
    }
        public partial class MemberRecruit
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int RecruitId { get; set; }
            public int MemberId { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey(nameof(MemberId))]
            [InverseProperty("MemberRecruits")]
            public virtual Member Member { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey(nameof(RecruitId))]
            [InverseProperty("MemberMembers")]
            public virtual Member Recruit { get; set; }
        }
```

and dbcontext

```
        public virtual DbSet<Member> Members{ get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MemberRecruit> MemberRecruits { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
          modelBuilder.Entity<MemberRecruit>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Member)
                    .WithMany(p => p.MemberRecruits)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.MemberId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);


                entity.HasOne(d => d.Recruit)
                    .WithMany(p => p.MemberMembers)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RecruitId);

            });
```

Since any member maybe a recruit of another members and member of another recruits it has 2 virtual collections - 1 shows the records where he is a member of another recruit( in memberId part ) , the second shows the records where he is a recruit of another member ( in recruitId part).  So if  you want to see all recruiters of member you can do it two ways

```
var recruiters=context.MemberRecruits
.Where(i=> i.MemberId==memberId)
.Select(i=>i.Recruit)
.ToList();
//or 
var recruits = _context.Members
.Where(i => i.Id == memberId)
.Select(i => i.MemberRecruits.Select(j => j.Recruit)).FirstOrDefault();
```

The second query looks a litle strange, but you should understand that members means  where  member is a member, recruits - where member as  a recruiter. Maybe better to rename the collections "AsMember" and "AsRecruiter". It's up to you.
Since it is much easier to query MemberRecruit , I would recomend to use it for queries.
Another example. Members where memberId is a recruiter

```
var members=context.MemberRecruits
.Where(i=> i.RecruiteId==memberId)
.Select(i=>i.Member)
.ToList();
```

Comment: If I use `.HasOne(mr => mr.Recruitment).WithMany(m => m.Recruits).HasForeignKey(mr => mr.UserId)`  for `Entity<MemberRecruit>`, when I query `member.Recruits[0].Recruitment` the result will be the original member, which is not what I want

Comment: @JasonYu  why are you going to use it? Pls try what I am offering. It was tested and it is working properly, the result will be Recruit

Comment: I did try but it's not working when I query `_db.Members.Include(x => x.MemberRecruitRecruites).ThenInclude(x => x.Recruit).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.MemberId == 1, token)`, it return exception ""The Include path 'MemberRecruit->Recruit' results in a cycle"

Comment: Furthermore, I am trying to define the mapping with DbContext only as the classes will be referenced from another project where it will not have the attribute to add those attributes.

Comment: Those naming in `Member` are not descriptive in the domain context, I guess in your code `MemberRecruitMembers` should be the "Recruiters" and `MemberRecruitRecruites` is "Recruitments"?

Comment: @JasonYu I am sorry I  don't  indertand what are you tryin to get with your queries. Please tell me what you need and I  will advise you what query to use.

Comment: without altering the existing 2 tables `Member` and `MemberRecruit` (which data comes from other system), using DbContext to map 2(or 1) domain models to the tables so that I can get the member's recruitments detail. Like the query in the example, if I select a member with id 1, then `member.Recuits.Select(x => (x.Recruitment.Id, x.Recruitment.Name))` return should be [(2,"Steve"),(3,"Bruce")]

Comment: @JasonYu I put some details in my answer. I hope it will help. Let me know if you still have some questions.

Comment: @Serge As usual, additional navigations are not mandatory as well as data annotations - the original model can be mapped fluently w/o any modification. But in general this is correct answer for many-to-many. However looking at the OP posted self answer, I'm not sure if they are after many-to-many and not a some weird design of a hierarchical (tree) data. Since it is unclear what is their problem and what they are trying to achieve, there is nothing we can do to help them out, moreover they believe they solved it in some weird way. The whole post is not useful for future readers.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you very much for your feedback , I really appreciate it. The problem is that it is referencing itself.  If it had 2 classes Member and Recruit I could add  -   public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }  and   public virtual ICollection<Recruit> Recruits { get; set; } and it would be working. But  is has only one class here. is it possible to add   public virtual ICollection<Member> Recruits { get; set; }  public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }  and how I can do this. What relations I need to add. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Serge Two `ICollection<Member>` are required only if you want to configure EFC 5+ many-to-many skip navigations. If you don't need skip navigations,  i.e. using explicit entity `MemberRecruit`, then the relationship can be configured with 0,1 or 2 collection mapped to 0,1 or 2 reference nav. properties. The fact that the it is referencing itself is not essential. I mean, you could always use `Has/With|One/Many` w/o argument, thus telling EF that there is no nav.  property at that side of the relationship. Once you have `Has` + `With` pair, you can use `HasForeignKey` to associate FK property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with your second option, per MS Docs [Single navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=data-annotations%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1), you can setup the navigation property by defining the relationship like this using the Fluent API.

Given the following class

```cs
public class Member
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<Member> Recruitments { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
        .HasMany(b => b.Member)
        .WithOne();
}
```

---

## Update

Given the following classes

```cs
public class Member
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<MemberRecruit> Recruitments { get; set; }
}

public class MemberRecruit
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int RecruitmentMemberId { get; set; }
   public Member RecruitmentMember { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
        .HasMany(b => b.MemberRecruit)
        .WithOne();

    modelBuilder.Entity<MemberRecruit>()
        .HasOne(b => b.RecruitmentMember)
        .WithOne();
}
```

You should be able to query it like this

```
var memeber = context.Member
              .Include(x => x.Recruitments)
              .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == request.Id);

var memberRecruitments = member.Recruitments
                         .Select(x => new Member 
                         {
                              Id = x.Id,
                              Name = x.Name 
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: How will this utilize the two table for this mapping?

Comment: @JasonYu, Sorry, I missed the bit about still using the same two tables. Though, I'm not sure what the point of the MemberRecruit  table would be if you are using this method. It seems like just using the Member table alone with this method satisfies the requirement. Could you clarify what you're going for with this?

Comment: There are 2 existing tables (let's say it's data comes from other system) that define the relationship between member and other members, it's like a tree structure where one member can link to N members which can link to more members, etc. I am trying to map that tables to the classes for better querying and it's not like I can alter the tables to fit my needs. I need to utilize the current tables to map this relationship.

Comment: @JasonYu, Ahh I see. I have updated my answer to use both existing tables.

Comment: that doesn't work, EF Core will throw exception saying "The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'MemberRecruit.Recruitment' and 'Member'."

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's the best practice but the following works

```
public class Member
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<MemberRecruit> Recruits { get; set; }
}

public class MemberRecruit
{
   public int MemberId { get; set; }
   public int RecruitmentMemberId { get; set; }
   public Member Recruitment { get; set; } // This is the recruited member
}
```

DbContext

```
builder.Entity<Member>(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("Member", "dbo");
    m.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    m.HasMany(x => x.Recruits)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(mr => mr.MemberId);
});

builder.Entity<MemberRecruit>(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("MemberRecruit", "dbo");
    m.HasKey(x => new
    {
        x.MemberId,
        x.RecruitmentMemberId
    });

    m.HasOne(x => x.Recruitment)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Member>(x => x.Id)
        .HasPrincipalKey<MemberRecruit>(x => x.RecruitmentMemberId);
});
```

Query and result

```
var member = await _db.Members
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.Recruits)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Recruitment)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == request.Id, token);
// If request.Id == 1
// member.Recruits.Count is 2
// member.Recruits[0].Recruitment will be (2, "Steve")
// member.Recruits[1].Recruitment will be (3, "Bruce")
```